# Updating rows added to an unbound a WinForms DataGridView fails silently - why?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

My Master/Detail form uses an unbound DataGridView to list Customers that match the filter Master section) selecting a row (RowEnter) in the DataGridView populates the detail section with values. I have a working Save button, that saves the form, rebinds the datagrid and then resets the form. The problem is updating the DataGridView when the detail change, now the bind method gets as far as dataGridView1.Rows.Clear() then exits but gives no error.

I need to get the form to save and the grid to update, also I need to understand why what I've currently got doesn't work.

```
private void dataGridView1_RowEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridViewCell dgc = dataGridView1["ID", int.Parse(e.RowIndex.ToString())];
        Guid customerID = Guid.Parse(dgc.Value.ToString());

        if (IsPageValid() && dataGridView1.Focused)
        {
            if (KeepChanges())
            {
                SaveForm();
                BindDataGrid(string.Empty);
            }
        }            

        Customer = _customerRepo.GetByID(customerID);
        BindCustomerDetails(Customer);
    }
```

The idea is that the form is loaded and a customer selected, some details are changed on the form and then a new customer is selected (another row is selected in the grid) and there are uncommitted changes. 
IsPageValid checks whether the details on the form would create a valid Customer.
KeepChanges returns from a MessageBox YesNo ("There are changes to this record. Do you want to keep them?") If the user clicks Yes then SaveForm() is called to persist the details. Then BindDataGrid(string.Empty) is called. Everything is fine up to this point, BindDataGrid(string.Empty) is called on Form_Load(), but this time when the line dataGridView1.Rows.Clear() is hit the debugger stops and control is returned to the program, none of the code beyond that point in the method is executed and I can't work out why.

```
public void BindDataGrid(String filterText)
    {
        var customers = String.IsNullOrEmpty(filterText) ? _customerRepo.GetAll() : _customerRepo.GetFiltered(filterText);

        dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
        dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 5;
        dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "ID";
        dataGridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false;
        dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "Name";
        dataGridView1.Columns[2].Name = "Address";
        dataGridView1.Columns[2].FillWeight = 300;
        dataGridView1.Columns[3].Name = "Phone";
        dataGridView1.Columns[3].FillWeight = 80;
        dataGridView1.Columns[4].Name = "Mobile";
        dataGridView1.Columns[4].FillWeight = 80;

        foreach (var customer in customers)
        {
            String address = String.IsNullOrEmpty(customer.Address.Street) ? "no address" : String.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}", customer.Address.Street, customer.Address.Town, customer.Address.County, customer.Address.Postcode);
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(customer.ID, customer.ToString(), address, customer.Address.Phone, customer.Mobile);
        }
    }
```

I have tried changing this to use a DataTable, setting the DataBinding to null and using a DataBinding object, but they all seem to run into the same problem. The DataGridView does not seem to update or allow updating. This, from the designer.cs file, doesn't seem to have anything that's preventing me as far as I can tell:

```
// dataGridView1
        // 
        this.dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
        this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
        this.dataGridView1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(4, 4);
        this.dataGridView1.Name = "dataGridView1";
        this.dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
        this.dataGridView1.SelectionMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
        this.dataGridView1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(736, 330);
        this.dataGridView1.TabIndex = 5;
        this.dataGridView1.RowEnter += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventHandler(this.dataGridView1_RowEnter);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to clear the rows from within a row event (RowEnter). This will almost certainly be throwing an exception that you need to catch.

The underlying issue is the rebinding of the data grid. I am pretty sure that you don't need to be doing this every time the data is saved. The most that you need to do is save the contents of the specific customer that is in the detail section.

If your underlying datasource supports IBindingList, then all you need to do is get the customer record from the grid and update it with the values from the form. Databinding should take care of updating the grid contents.

See the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource.aspx) on the DataSource property for more information.

Comment: good point about the underlying issue there have modified so I just update the DataGridViewRow for the changed Customer. I need to mentally resolve that it's read only so it doesn't matter what I do to the values there it doesn't affect the actual database.
My Customers data is an IList so it _should have_ been easy to convert to IBindingList and use that. However when I tried to modify my code as per the MSDN I got NullReference exceptions (`dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1`), though that looks interesting and new to me (I'm a web dev by trade, this is all new to me)

Comment: Now I'm not clearing the rows from a row event the rest of the method executes as normal; the weird thing is that it didn't appear to throw any exception, I could step right up to it in the debugger.

Comment: You shouldn't need the bindingsource1, you should be able to just set the DataSource directly to your customer collection. Implementing IBindingList can seem a little tricky at first, but if you start simple (don't try implementing searching and sorting right away), you should be able to knock it out pretty quickly.